# Foreign keys and IntegrityError: id may not be NULL

Tags: django, django-models

Django newbie here. I have two simple models like this:

```
class Fluff(models.Model):
    # ....
    # some fields definitions

class Something(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    fluff = models.ForeignKey(Fluff)
```

`syncdb` goes as expected, and then I go to the shell to test things:

```
>>> s = Something()
>>> s.name = 'Blah'
>>> s.fluff = Fluff(...)
>>> s.save()
Traceback (most recent call last): # traceback skipped for brevity
IntegrityError: app_something.fluff_id may not be NULL
```

I expected Django to do its magic, figure out `fluff` is not saved, then save it before saving `s`. That didn't happen, but it's OK, I can save `fluff` for myself, let's try again:

```
>>> s = Something()
>>> s.name = 'Blah'
>>> s.fluff = Fluff(...)
>>> s.fluff.save()
>>> s.save()
Traceback (most recent call last): # traceback skipped for brevity
IntegrityError: app_something.fluff_id may not be NULL
```

No luck. This should be trivial, but I cannot figure it out at the moment. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

```
>>> s.name = 'Blah'
>>> obj = Fluff(...)
>>> obj.save()
>>> s.fluff = obj
>>> s.save()
```

Comment: OK, that worked... but is this the idiomatic way of doing things? Seems rather clumsy to me. Especially since in my scenario, I'd like to generate a couple of `Something`s and only save some based on user input. I can see that leading to lines like `s.fluff = s.fluff` just so I don't carry extra variables along with `s`...

Comment: I just thought it will work. You will need to get or create object before assign it with field of other models. It's really easy to understand what is going on in code, so I think it is good way to do. Really, I don't look at models system, but I think when you use s.fluff = Fluff(...) - only id set in that field in database (integer), so you can's save it.

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine why your code works and mine doesn't; that doesn't mean I have to like it :) Anyway, thanks for your time, I'll wait a bit before accepting your answer just in case some other suggestion pops up.