# Django IntegrityError with relationship in model

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a recipe/ingredient model in Django

In my models.py I got

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, blank=True)
```

But when I create a Recipe or Ingredient in my admin, I get :

```
IntegrityError at /admin/menuview/ingredient/add/
menuview_ingredient.recipe_id may not be NULL
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think, view code is needed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to give relationship a null=True parameter too.

```
ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredients, blank=True, null=True,)
```

Comment: I tried, but still doesn't work. When I make the change, do I only have to execute : python manage.py syncdb ?

Comment: @Speccy Syncdb only creates new tables.  When you change an existing table, you have to drop the table before running syncdb again, or modify the table in place.  You could do it right in the db shell, but [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) is a much better way to go.

Comment: unfortunalely syncdb does not change already existed tables. you can use sqldiff from django_extentions to get diff sql of that table, or just dump db and create it with syncdb. Or just open your db and make menuview_ingredient.recipe_id field not mandatory

Comment: I think you were right, it finally worked after I trashed my db and created a new one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is similar to this one: [Foreign keys and IntegrityError: id may not be NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215279/foreign-keys-and-integrityerror-id-may-not-be-null)

To fix it, you will do something similar to this when saving:

```
>>> s = Recipe()
>>> s.name = 'Blah'
>>> obj = Ingredient(...)
>>> obj.save()
>>> s.ingredients = obj
>>> s.save()
```

The [Django Doc has more examples for `ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/). For example, for your case:

```
>>> i = Ingredient.objects.get(id=1)
>>> e = i.recipe_set.create(
...     name ='strawberry pancake',
... )
# No need to call e.save() at this point -- it's already been saved.
```

> This is equivalent to (but much simpler than):

```
>>> i = Ingredient.objects.get(id=1)
>>> e = Recipe(
...     ingredients=i,       
...     name='strawberry pancacke',
... )
>>> e.save(force_insert=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not even there : the admin page add generate the error